# Create a powershell script to place a custom word template in the templates folder

Tags: powershell, templates, registry, cpu-word

I want to place a word template, template.dotm into the Word custom templates folder.

Using Office 365, latest version of Word. Windows 10. Apologies if my terminology is incorrect, still a powershell/programming novice.

This folder doesn't exist by default, and the directory Word looks for default templates in doesn't exist by default either. If a user has created a template, then it will create an expanding string named PersonalTemplates at the following registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options, with the value being the directory they've elected as their default custom templates directory.

I want to make a script which:

- Checks for presence of PersonalTemplates. If present, and value is not null, store as $regvalue.
- If not present, or value is null, create expanding string with the following value $newreg at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options.
- Then copy template.dotm into the $regvalue or $newreg. Powershell will be run from the same directory as the template.dotm is stored in.

I've got a bunch of snippets which do some of the principle operations, though I can't work out how to tie them together, and am missing some bits which I just can't work out:

Copy the template to the destination

> ForEach ($user in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Exclude Public)) {
> New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\Users$($user.Name)\Documents\Custom Office Templates"
> Copy-Item template.dotm -Destination "C:\Users$($user.Name)\Documents\Custom Office Templates"

Create registry key with value

> Set-Location -Path
> 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options'
>
> New-ItemProperty -Path
> 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options' -Name
> 'PersonalTemplates' -Value "C:\Users$($user.Name)\Documents\Custom
> Office Templates" -PropertyType ExpandString -Force }

Get regvalue

> $regvalue = (Get-ItemPropertyValue
> 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options'
> 'PersonalTemplates')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together your code snippets in order, also corrected the logic for checking if the Registry key is present or not.

```
ForEach ($user in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Exclude Public)) 
{ 

  $location = "C:\Users\$($user.Name)\Documents\Custom Office Templates"
  $IsPresent = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options' | ForEach-Object {If($_ -like '*PersonalTemplates*'){ Return 'True' }}
  if(-Not($IsPresent -eq 'True'))
  { 
    New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options' -Name 'PersonalTemplates' -Value $location -PropertyType ExpandString -Force   \\Not tested
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $location  
  }

  $existingValue= Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options' -Name 'PersonalTemplates'

  if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($existingValue)){
   Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options' -Name 'PersonalTemplates' -Value  $location
  }
  else{
   $location=$existingValue
   if(!(test-path $existingValue))
     {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $existingValue
     }
  }


  Copy-Item template.dotm -Destination $location
}
```

I have not tested the creation of registry key as I am on my work laptop, so assuming that line of code works.

Also, question for you: With this approach wouldn't the registry entry have the single value that of the first user folder, you may have to look into the logic? I feel you may have to run this script for each user after they login using `$env:Username` instead of looping through the user folder. But I could be wrong, there may be other who could suggest better.

Comment: Thank you for the quick follow up, I really appreciate it!

I'll try this shortly. Indeed, what you pose could be a problem. I can cope with it in this instance as the fleet of machines this will run on have a known set of user accounts, admin, user, public, so I can exclude the admin and public accounts which would then only include the user account. But perhaps a better way to do it would be to select the currently logged in user somehow?

Comment: Yes, that's what I assume. You can get current logged in user name using the variable $env:Username which will be same as the folder name under users folder.

Comment: Hi, just had a chance to look at this. Thank you, it was helpful, however it doesn't do one of the requirements which is to use the registry value as the directory to copy a file to if the registry exists and has a value. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have updated the logic to use the directory from the registry, if it already exists. Sorry i haven't tested the code as I dont have my machine with me now, but the logic is pretty much it.

Comment: Hi, thank you! That's helpful again. I (think I have) simplified this and posted it as another answer (I've tested my answer, seems to work fine). I think we're nearly there... however I also need to cope for the situation that the $IsPresent is true but $regvalue is null or empty. I thought a good way to do so would be something like ($regvalue -notlike '*:\*').

Any ideas where this would fit in either your or my answer? Thank you so much yet again!

Comment: @SVR I have updated the code to handle null or empty or just white spaced registry value condition. Never expected a registry value to be an empty string though.

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I've really been trying to get this to work so as to not bother you, however it's writing out $($user.Name) instead of the username, which I *think* is because of the else at the bottom looping. I prefer to use this method for selecting the user as $env:username selects the powershell user, which may not necessarily be the same as the logged in user.

Comment: In the code I provided in a seperate answer, is it possible to make $IsPresent true only if registry present AND NOT NullOrWhiteSpace? I feel like this could be a really simple way of getting there...

Comment: The user name printing as $($user.Name) is because of the single quote used to assign the default location, my bad typo. I have updated the code so that the location variable uses double quote
$location = "C:\Users\$($user.Name)\Documents\Custom Office Templates"

Comment: The issue with Get-ItemPropertyValue is that it doesn't honor -ErrorAction parameter, so if the registry key is not present it will throw an error and the script will stop, hence I decided to call it after creating a new entry if not present. Let me have a thought and see if the script can be simplified.

Comment: Hi, that all works really nicely! Thank you. The next hurdle I've now come across is that if $location does not end with a backslash (and by default the $existingValue Word creates *if* it does create one doesn't) then it creates a file called "Custom Office Templates" rather than a directory.

My intuition is that this a simple fix.. but I wasn't able to work it out!

Comment: when you are creating a directory using the New-Item command, use the ItemType parameter to say its a directory, that way it doesnt matter if you have a backslash

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $location

Comment: Hi, sorry, I musn't have been clear. When I run the code above, it works in all circumstances except when the $location already exists and it doesn't end in a \. 

In this circumstances, it runs, but creates a file called "Custom Office Templates" with the file size of the template.dotm, and no file extension.

When I manually run the last line $location+'\' it will work, however obviously this could cause problems where we have a value present prior the script running that already ends in a '\'

Comment: @SVR hey, thats another scenario to handle. registry key has a path that is not actually present. I updated the code to create the existing location if not present.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working nicely in testing. I really appreciate your help. This will be really useful.